# How to keep a Modal open even after refreshing in Materialize CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I want to keep a Modal open after refreshing in Materialize CSS Framework.
Because I have a Form in Modal & I want to when the Form submitted if It had a problem Redirect Back to show errors in Modal, So I want to keep it open unless the user close that ...
How can I do that ?

Comment: A better option is to use ajax call to submit the form, and according to the response to hide the modal.

Comment: @Dekel Thanks, It's a good way ...